# How to set image quality when writing a gif with Bitmaps?

Tags: .net, bitmap, gif

I am creating small images with System.Drawing.Common bitmap.
When I use png as output, the results are as I expect (but still, of course). Here is a sample picture:
[image]

When I save an image as gif, the movement is as I want, but the encoder seems to put heavy restraints on the color pallete:
[image]

Is there a way to circumvent this compression? Filesize is not of my concern.
Additionally, the infinite loop for the gif won't work.
If possible, I'm looking for a native solution and not some plugins/external libraries to put in my code.
This is the code right now to generate a gif (derived from another stack overflow question):

```
public class Gif
{
    // Gdi+ constants absent from System.Drawing.
    const int PropertyTagFrameDelay = 0x5100;
    const int PropertyTagLoopCount = 0x5101;
    const short PropertyTagTypeLong = 4;
    const short PropertyTagTypeShort = 3;
    const int UintBytes = 4;
    public static void MergeFrames(string outputPath, Bitmap[] src, double fps = 25)
    {
        var gifEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Gif);
        // Params of the first frame.
        var encoderParams1 = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParams1.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
        // Params of other frames.
        var encoderParamsN = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParamsN.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionTime);
        // Params for the finalizing call.
        var encoderParamsFlush = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParamsFlush.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);

        // PropertyItem for the frame delay (apparently, no other way to create a fresh instance).
        var frameDelay = (PropertyItem)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(PropertyItem));
        frameDelay.Id = PropertyTagFrameDelay;
        frameDelay.Type = PropertyTagTypeLong;
        // Length of the value in bytes.
        frameDelay.Len = src.Length * UintBytes;
        // The value is an array of 4-byte entries: one per frame.
        // Every entry is the frame delay in 1/100-s of a second, in little endian.
        frameDelay.Value = new byte[src.Length * UintBytes];
        // E.g., here, we're setting the delay of every frame to 1 second.
        var frameDelayBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)(100/fps));
        for (int j = 0; j < src.Length; ++j)
            Array.Copy(frameDelayBytes, 0, frameDelay.Value, j * UintBytes, UintBytes);

        // PropertyItem for the number of animation loops.
        var loopPropertyItem = (PropertyItem)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(PropertyItem));
        loopPropertyItem.Id = PropertyTagLoopCount;
        loopPropertyItem.Type = PropertyTagTypeShort;
        loopPropertyItem.Len = 0;
        // 0 means to animate forever.
        loopPropertyItem.Value = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)0);

        if (!outputPath.EndsWith(".gif")) outputPath += ".gif";
        using (var stream = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            bool first = true;
            Bitmap firstBitmap = null;
            // Bitmaps is a collection of Bitmap instances that'll become gif frames.
            foreach (var bitmap in src)
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    firstBitmap = bitmap;
                    firstBitmap.SetPropertyItem(frameDelay);
                    firstBitmap.SetPropertyItem(loopPropertyItem);
                    firstBitmap.Save(stream, gifEncoder, encoderParams1);
                    first = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    firstBitmap.SaveAdd(bitmap, encoderParamsN);
                }
            }
            firstBitmap.SaveAdd(encoderParamsFlush);
        }

    }
    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately gif is fairly limited.
one could use webp or apng instead.
The easiest way I found so far to generate these is to use ffmpeg to convert the images.
ffmped needs to be installed.

simplistic ffmpeg wrapper:

```
public class ffmpeg
{
    public static string Execute(string parameters)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;
        var path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = parameters;
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();

            result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            { }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

conversion to webp:

1. save images to folder
2. convert images with ffmpeg:

```
public class WebP
{
    private static string ImagePath = "ffmpeg\\temp";
    public static void MergeFrames( System.Drawing.Bitmap[] src, double fps = 25, bool lossless = true)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(ImagePath))
        {
            Directory.Delete(ImagePath, true);
        }
        Directory.CreateDirectory(ImagePath);
        for(int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++)
        {
            src[i].Save(ImagePath+$"\\TEST-{i}.png");
        }
        string result = ffmpeg.ffmpeg.Execute("-f image2 -framerate 25 -stream_loop -1 -start_number 1 -i \"ffmpeg\\temp\\TEST-%01d.png\" 0000video.webp");
        { }
    }
}
```